# Why does "Ꙭ".codePointAt(0)==205 and other Java Character bizarreness?

Tags: java, unicode

(Lest this get closed as too localized, I chose Ꙭ as an example but this happens for many other characters also)

The character Ꙭ is \uA66C or decimal 42604 (http://unicodinator.com/#A66C).  I'm seeing some very weird things I can't understand while using Java's Character class.

```
1) Character.isLetter('Ꙭ');//won't compile, complains 'unclosed character literal'
2) Character.isLetter("Ꙭ".charAt(0)); //returns true, which is right
3) Character.isLetter(42604);//returns false
4) Character.isLetter('\uA66C');//returns false
5) "Ꙭ".codePointAt(0);//returns 205? 205 is Í http://unicodinator.com/#00CD
6) ("Ꙭ".charAt(0)==(char)42604) //is false
```

Everything except #2 does not make sense to me.  This character is in the BMP and is not from \uD800 to \uDFFF so there shouldn't be any complexity with surrogates.  It seems like I'm missing some key concept here...

Comment: This was uncovered as part of troubleshooting an issue for my JavaScript unicode utility https://github.com/joelarson4/CharFunk

Comment: That character is... distracting.

Comment: I think you may need to check the character set of your text editor/IDE vs how Java itself would like to see the results. It almost seems like there is a character set mismatch. And is this for Java? Or JavaScript? They are completely different...

Comment: I can't reproduce this behavior. Can you say something more about how you are running this code? What encoding you use in your project/source files?

Comment: @Pshemo -- can you reproduce #3 and #4?

Comment: @MarkOrmston - I tagged the question java, it is java.  I'm using Sublime Text 2 and saving with UTF-8.  Meanwhile, character set issues wouldn't explain #3 and #4.

Comment: @PaulBellora: Not as bad as ꙮ (CYRILLIC LETTER MULTIOCULAR O)

Comment: Nope, my results are 1-4) -> `true`  5) `42604`, 6) `true`. I am using Eclipse and entire project have utf-8 encoding.

Comment: @Pshemo somehow I was running Java 6 instead of 7, and that's the difference

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks as if the character encoding your editor is using is different from that used by javac (or equivalent compiler). javac will default to picking up whichever encoding happens to be set as default on your machine. Use `-encoding` to change for javac.

Ꙭ in UTF-8 will appear in Latin 1 (or similar) as ê¬ (0xEA 0x99 0xAD), which isn't valid for a character literal as it is three characters.

As for 3 and 4, it apparently was introduced in the relatively new Unicode 5.1.0 (March 2008), which presumably isn't supported by the version of Java you are using. Apparently Java SE 6 uses Unicode 4.0; Java SE 7 uses Unicode 6.0.0.

Most people stick to US ASCII for source files, with good reason.

Comment: I'm using Sublime Text 2 and saving with UTF-8 encoding.  I'm running javac and java from the command line.  Still, even if this was incorrect, it doesn't explain #3 and #4 -- this character is a definitely letter according to the unicode spec, category "Lu" http://codepoints.net/U+A66C.

Comment: @joelarson As edit, only in a recent version of Unicode. javac will default to picking up whichever encoding happens to be set as default on your machine. Use `-encoding` to change. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/javac.html

Comment: Apparently Java SE 6 uses Unicode 4.0; Java SE 7 uses Unicode 6.0.0.

Comment: OK, weird it seems like my machine has reverted to Java 6 somehow... gah!

Comment: ok, it was just because of Java 6 -- with Java 7 the mysteriousness goes away!  If you mention that in your answer I will chose it as the answer.

Comment: Going to have to refuse that "Most people stick to US ASCII for source files, with good reason" claim, since I don't really know anyone who doesn't make their text editor or IDE default to UTF8 encoding (which is identical to US ASCII as far as computers are concerned until you use character with a code higher than 0x0F, since UTF8's first 127 characters are the US ASCII set, and UTF8 doesn't need a BOM code at the start of a file). If you're coding in ASCII, you're also coding in UTF8 =)